# DATEDIFF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I am using `DATEDIFF`, however, I got unexpected results.

I tried to calculate the `Reminder` column by `minus 5 days` from the calculated `deadline` column.

I received some results but they don't make sense.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT n.LastReceiptDate, 
DATEADD(dd, 10, n.LastReceiptDate) AS deadline, 
DATEDIFF(dd, 5, DATEADD(dd, 10, n.LastReceiptDate)) AS Reminder 
FROM Table n;
```

[image]

Comment: DateDiff takes a date as the second parameter, you've specified `5` which is something like `5 Jan 1900`. Always worth checking the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks, how can I get date that is 5 days before the "deadline" column?

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes I know I can do that, I was just wondering if I can do it by using DATEDIFF

Comment: You can't do it with DateDiff, because DateDiff (Date difference) calculates the difference in the given intervals between two dates. It does not return a date. You want **DateAdd**. Use the proper function. If someone told you that you had to do it with DateDiff, the proper response is *No, because you need to use DateAdd instead*. And please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. All you've done is repeat the tag information, which is redundant, and removing *SQL Server* and *DATEDIFF* from that title leaves *in*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT n.LastReceiptDate, 
DATEADD(dd, 10, n.LastReceiptDate) AS deadline, 
DATEADD(dd, -5, DATEADD(dd, 10, n.LastReceiptDate)) AS Reminder 
FROM Table n;
```